# In CSS 3, why using `@keyframes` doesn't work here?

Tags: html, css, animation, keyframe

Below are the codes:

```css
div.circle {
  height: 134px;
  width: 134px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 50vh auto 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
@keyframes example {
  from : {
    height: 134px;
    width: 134px;
  }
  to : {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

I want to make the circle larger by using `@keyframes` in CSS. However, I found there is no animation at all in Chrome even I added `animation-name` and `animation-duration` for that element. (Moreover, adding browser-prefix doesn't fix this..)

Does anyone have any ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: Typo error. Please remove the `:` after `from` and `to` within the `@keyframes` rule.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_keyframes you can take refrence from here

Comment: @Harry It works, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your css code should be:

```
div.circle {
    height: 134px;
    width: 134px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 50vh auto 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    //animation-name: example;
    //animation-duration: 2s;
    animation: example 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: example 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes example {
    from {
        height: 134px;
        width: 134px;
    }
    to {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {
        height: 134px;
        width: 134px;
    }
    to {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6xnenv02/)

There were two things wrong with your code.

You need to use `@-webkit-keyframes` for chrome browser.
Second thing is that you need to remove `:` from `from : {` and `to : {` , because that is a syntax error.